# The type 'KPIGetter_Library.KPIGetter', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive,

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am writing my first restful wcf service. 
I have written a WCF Library. It tests out using the dev webserver. 
All good till deployment.

I followed this very nice article to deploy this to IIS7 on a win2008 server box.
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx

I am getting this message.

The type 'KPIGetter_Library.KPIGetter', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Below is the single line in my KpiGetter.svc text file

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="KPIGetter_Library.KPIGetter" %>
```

The namespace and class name are correct. How does the website know to look in the DLL to find this. There are 3 DLLs in the folder. My guess is just matching the DLL name to the namespace.

There is a web.config that I added per the article mentioned above. 
There is an KPIGetter_Library.dll.config  that was renamed from App.config from the library project. 
Its contents are listed here. Again, this works in the dev environment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>

    <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="KPIGetter_Library.KPIGetter">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="KPIGetter_Library.IKpiGetter" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour">

                </endpoint>

                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://hodbd05:8000/kpigetter"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>

                <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        </protocolMapping>

    </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

If anyone could offere suggestions, or offer an article that may help me trouble shoot this, i would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Alright.

The issue is that the KPIGetter.svc file and the web.config file need to be in the folder you point to from IIS. 
The dlls need to be in a bin folder. 
Fair enough.

Also, the web.config file needs to be merged w/ the contents of the *.dll.config file (which ultimately was the app.config file in your project. Also fair enough.

As a troubleshooting technique, I created and shared a second folder on my server and then published to that folder from my visStudio. Here I was able to see that it wanted a BIN folder. It also gave me a pretty good web.config. I just had to go edit the HostUrl.

Once I did this, I got an error that my connection string was wrong. I knew at that point I was home free.

The article I mention does do a good job of detailing the security that has to be setup on the folder. It also details the couple of simple steps you need to do in IIS (setup a pool, create a website, etc)

Hope this helps someone, this cost me a day or so.

Cheers

greg